# Increase Performance of Nested For Loop in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

The following is subset of Large Data Frame having 158K observations named "sh_data".

```
Patient_ID Age_in_days DEMAdmNo 
396076 28542 0 
396076 28570 0 
396076 28598 0 
396076 28626 0 
396076 28654 0 
396076 28682 0 
396076 28710 0 
396076 28738 0 
396076 28766 0 
396076 28794 0 
396076 28822 0 
396076 28850 0 
396076 28878 0 
396076 28906 0 
396076 28934 0 
396076 28962 0 
396076 28990 0 
396076 29018 0 
396076 29046 0 
396076 29074 0 
396076 29102 1 
396076 29165 0 
396076 29200 0 
396076 29228 0 
396076 29263 0 
396076 29200 0 
396076 29228 0 
396076 29263 0
```

I am trying to calculate the number of instances for a record in past six months where 3rd Column is 1 (denoted as LACE_E). So for first record, where age is minimum it will be zero. And for second record if age difference in days is <= 183 days and column 3 for first record is zero then it will be one and so on.

I worte the following query in R:

```
LACE_E <- numeric(0)

for(i in 1:length(sh_data[,1]))
{
  LACE_E[i] = 0
  for(j in 1:length(sh_data[,1]))
  {
    if(sh_data$Patient_ID[i] == sh_data$Patient_ID[j] & sh_data$Age_in_days[i] > sh_data$Age_in_days[j] & (sh_data$Age_in_days[i]- sh_data$Age_in_days[j])<= 183 & sh_data$DEMAdmNo[j] == 1)
    {LACE_E[i] = LACE_E[i] + 1}
  }
}
```

This query is taking long time to process. 1 hour to process 100 rows in my system. Please Help!!

Comment: There is no NRIC in your data

Comment: Sorry...NRIC is the Patient ID. Let me correct that. Thanks.

Comment: This can be very easily done in `data.table` or `dplyr`. Pose your problem correctly: get rid of long names, add more variations to `Patient ID` and `Demadno`, and add your desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to go to `Rcpp` or `data.table` to get very significant improvements.

Taking your original data and replicating it to get more usable timings:

```
d <- read.table(head = TRUE, text = 
"Patient_ID Age_in_days DEMAdmNo 
396076 28542 0 
396076 28570 0 
396076 28598 0 
396076 28626 0 
396076 28654 0 
396076 28682 0 
396076 28710 0 
396076 28738 0 
396076 28766 0 
396076 28794 0 
396076 28822 0 
396076 28850 0 
396076 28878 0 
396076 28906 0 
396076 28934 0 
396076 28962 0 
396076 28990 0 
396076 29018 0 
396076 29046 0 
396076 29074 0 
396076 29102 1 
396076 29165 0 
396076 29200 0 
396076 29228 0 
396076 29263 0 
396076 29200 0 
396076 29228 0 
396076 29263 0 ")

d <- rbind(d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d)
```

Your original code as a function and a timing run:

```
f0 <- function(sh_data) {
    LACE_E <- numeric(0)

    for(i in 1:length(sh_data[,1])) {
        LACE_E[i] = 0
        for(j in 1:length(sh_data[,1])) {
            if(sh_data$Patient_ID[i] == sh_data$Patient_ID[j] &
               sh_data$Age_in_days[i] > sh_data$Age_in_days[j] &
               (sh_data$Age_in_days[i]- sh_data$Age_in_days[j])<= 183 &
               sh_data$DEMAdmNo[j] == 1) {
                LACE_E[i] = LACE_E[i] + 1
            }
        }
    }
}

system.time(v0 <- f0(d))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  4.803   0.007   4.812
```

Profiling shows about 90% time spent in extracting columns with `$` in the inner loop:

```
Rprof()
v0 <- f0(d)
Rprof(NULL)
head(summaryRprof()$by.total)
## "f0"                  4.94    100.00      0.60    12.15
## "$"                   4.24     85.83      0.72    14.57
## "$.data.frame"        3.52     71.26      0.36     7.29
## "[["                  3.16     63.97      0.46     9.31
## "[[.data.frame"       2.70     54.66      0.96    19.43
## "%in%"                0.92     18.62      0.22     4.45
```

Moving the column extractions out of the loops improves performance substantially:

```
f1 <- function(sh_data) {
    LACE_E <- numeric(0)

    Patient_ID <- sh_data$Patient_ID
    Age_in_days <- sh_data$Age_in_days
    DEMAdmNo <- sh_data$DEMAdmNo
    for(i in 1:length(sh_data[,1])) {
        LACE_E[i] = 0
        for(j in 1:length(sh_data[,1])) {
            if(Patient_ID[i] == Patient_ID[j] &
               Age_in_days[i] > Age_in_days[j] &
               (Age_in_days[i]- Age_in_days[j])<= 183 &
               DEMAdmNo[j] == 1) {
                LACE_E[i] = LACE_E[i] + 1
            }
        }
    }
}

system.time(v1 <- f1(d))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.163   0.000   0.164
```

It is almost always a bad idead to start with an empty result and grow it; pre-allocating the result is better practice. In this case the algorithm is already `O(n^2)` so you don't notice much, but it does make a difference, especially after adding other improvements. `f2` pre-allocates the result:

```
f2 <- function(sh_data) {
    n <- nrow(sh_data)
    LACE_E <- numeric(n)

    Patient_ID <- sh_data$Patient_ID
    Age_in_days <- sh_data$Age_in_days
    DEMAdmNo <- sh_data$DEMAdmNo
    for(i in 1:n) {
        LACE_E[i] = 0
        for(j in 1:n) {
            if(Patient_ID[i] == Patient_ID[j] &
               Age_in_days[i] > Age_in_days[j] &
               (Age_in_days[i]- Age_in_days[j])<= 183 &
               DEMAdmNo[j] == 1) {
                LACE_E[i] = LACE_E[i] + 1
            }
        }
    }
}

system.time(v2 <- f2(d))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.147   0.000   0.148
```

Using the right logical operator `&&` instead of `&` improves things further:

```
f3 <- function(sh_data) {
    n <- nrow(sh_data)
    LACE_E <- numeric(n)

    Patient_ID <- sh_data$Patient_ID
    Age_in_days <- sh_data$Age_in_days
    DEMAdmNo <- sh_data$DEMAdmNo
    for(i in 1:n) {
        LACE_E[i] = 0
        for(j in 1:n) {
            if(Patient_ID[i] == Patient_ID[j] &&
               Age_in_days[i] > Age_in_days[j] &&
               (Age_in_days[i] - Age_in_days[j]) <= 183 &&
               DEMAdmNo[j] == 1) {
                LACE_E[i] = LACE_E[i] + 1
            }
        }
    }
}

system.time(v3 <- f3(d))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.108   0.002   0.111
```

These are all steps you need to take to go to `Rcpp`, but you don't need to go to `Rcpp` to take them.

To get a bit more speed you can byte compile:

```
f3c <- compiler::cmpfun(f3)
system.time(v3 <- f3c(d))
##   user  system elapsed 
## 0.036   0.000   0.036
```

These computations were done in R 3.1.3. A `microbenchmark` summary:

```
microbenchmark(f0(d), f1(d), f2(d), f3(d), f3c(d), times = 10)
## Unit: milliseconds
##   expr        min        lq       mean     median         uq        max  neval  cld
##   f0(d) 5909.39756 5924.8493 5963.63608 5947.23469 6011.94567 6048.03571    10    d
##   f1(d)  196.16466  197.3252  200.22471  197.93345  202.49236  210.22011    10   c 
##   f2(d)  187.68169  190.5644  194.02454  192.47596  195.63821  204.27415    10   c 
##   f3(d)  109.17816  110.6695  112.55218  111.93915  114.43341  116.92342    10  b  
##  f3c(d)   37.37348   38.8757   39.34564   39.58563   40.50597   40.58568    10 a

R.version$version.string
## [1] "R version 3.1.3 Patched (2015-03-16 r68072)"
```

R 3.2.0 to be released in April has a number of improvements to the interpreter and byte code engine, which improves performance further:

```
## Unit: milliseconds
##    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval  cld
##   f0(d) 4351.33908 4429.71559 4471.32960 4479.13901 4499.39769 4601.05390    10    d
##   f1(d)  183.57765  184.68961  190.10391  187.30951  199.56235  200.57238    10   c 
##   f2(d)  177.47063  181.09790  189.78291  185.58951  190.34782  233.90264    10   c 
##   f3(d)  105.79767  108.02553  114.48950  110.17056  112.85710  149.42474    10  b  
##  f3c(d)   14.41182   14.43227   14.70098   14.49289   14.84504   15.67709    10 a   

R.version$version.string
## [1] "R Under development (unstable) (2015-03-24 r68072)"
```

So good R programming pracitices and use of performance analysis tools can take you a long way. If you want further improvement you can go to `Rcpp` but this may be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Luke for the detailed explanation. I was able achieve the required results with f3c in 2 hrs of run time in my system for 158k rows. Appreciate you help!!

Comment: @Hemu, I think you selected my answer instead of Luke's. Luke, I would tend to agree with you but from my experience (dealing with at least some hundrends' of millions of lines), the pure-R apporaches do not scale well, especially if the formula becomes more complex.

Comment: I was under the impression that we can select multiple solutions. Hence I clicked on both but only the later clicked solution got accepted as solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is better achieved using `Rcpp` and `data.table`. You don't really need to be doing the for-loops in R for this problem.

My I suggest the following approach?

Create a new `source.cpp` file as follows (example directory is C:\Projects)

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List myFunction(NumericVector x,NumericVector y) {
  const int n(x.size());
  NumericVector res(n);
  // x is age_in_days
  // y is DEMAAdmNo
  for (int i=1; i<n; i++)  {
       res[i]=0;
       for (int j=1; j<j; j++) {
            if ( (x[i]>x[j]) & ((x[i]-x[j])<=183) & (y[j]==1)) {
            res[i]=res[i]+1;
            }
       }
  }
  return Rcpp::List::create(_["res"] = res);
}
```

if you don't have the `Rcpp` package installed, please do so and load the cpp file created above like this:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp('C:/Projects/source.cpp')
```

Then, in your main file, do the following:

```
library(data.table) #If not installed, do install.packages('data.table')
sh_data=fread('C:/Projects/data3.csv') #Please put your correct file path here
sh_data[, LACE_E := myFunction(Age_in_days, DEMAdmNo), by=Patient_ID]
```

I couldn't verify the numbers as you haven't specified what output you want, so please adjust the `if` statement in the `cpp` file.

In any case, a combination of `Rcpp` and `data.table` will save you a lot of time. Highly recommended.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nikos for the approach and introduction to Rcpp. Unfortunately I was not able to load Rtools in my system. Though I was able to install appropriate Version, R was not recognizing the installation. Will try this approach in a different system.

Comment: No problem,thanks for your feedback. Hope you find a good solution.